# HP Notebook (F387wm); Internal PCIe slots & internal USB ports..?

Tags: usb, pci-express

Wasssup folks! I've been on and off this forum for a short time and find some good info here! I'll make this brief..

I cannot take my laptop apart (I'm in  motel with 3 small kids and they hover like whoa...)..So i can't just look and figure it out myself like I normally would..

Having some luck on google but not enough.

So there are interna USB ports and internal PCIe slots in this laptop (Hp 15" Notebook...15-F387wm), and I am curious what exactly these internal ports are.

Is it just a motherboard connection where a hub is soldered?

Or is it an actual USB port with an adapter?

Same for the internal (m)PCIe slots.. I"m aware there are 4 or 5 mPCIe Gen 2 slots.

I am asking because I'm upgrading this thing and I would like to avoid using the external USB 3.0 slots to keep it looking somewhat clean and to keep the ports open.

So what exactly are these internal connections?

Tried looking at a few pics form this site and the links were no good.

Comment: Please format better your question so it isn't just one long phrase.

Comment: Not a proper answer but HP typically has decent service manuals that might show what these do. [This seems to be the one for your model](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04763947)

Comment: "So there are interna USB ports and internal PCIe slots in this laptop" - where did you get this ideas from?

Answer (score 0):

Only user serviceable-upgradable internal parts-ports on that model are memory, hard drive, Wireless card and:

32gb emmc module which requires extensive disassembly of laptop).

Everything else is an integral part of the motherboard.

[Your support page](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-15-f300-notebook-pc-series-touch/8961458/model/10098384/manuals)